# How to get biggest group of nodes connected to each other?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I've been given huge graph of nodes randomly connected. I need to get biggest group of nodes where each on is connected with each other node in group.

I can solve it using bruteforce, but I'd like to know if there isn't any better way to do it.

Comment: Maximal clique is NP-hard - you can see this by considering the maximal clique as it applies to the maximum independent set problem (consider the complement graph).

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem consists of finding the [maximal clique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) in the graph. There are several algorithms in literature which should get you started